# Error de Actualización de Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

!Buenas!

Me aparece que tengo disponible unas actualizaciones disponibles en el **IDE de Eclipse**. Pero al intentad actualizar todos estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me salta este error al finalizar, y no actualiza y no hace nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el código de error, ya que es mas largo y no entraba en la imagen:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_Daniel_eclipse_java-2018-12_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient.win,4.5.6.v20190213-1947
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.sshd.sftp,2.2.0.v20190425-2127
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.ui,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core,1.7.6.v20190415-1216
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core.win32,1.7.6.v20190415-1216
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.help.ui,1.7.6.v20190415-1216
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui,1.7.6.v20190416-1746
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui.css,1.7.6.v20190415-1216
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,5.4.0.201905062345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,5.4.0.201905062345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache,5.4.0.201905062345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.lfs,5.4.0.201905062345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.lfs.server,5.4.0.201905062345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache,5.4.0.201905062345
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.jcraft.jsch,0.1.55.v20190404-1902
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.sshd.osgi,2.2.0.v20190425-2127
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.feature,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,5.4.0.201905091036
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.epp.mpc,1.7.6.v20190416-1746
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,5.4.0.201905070004
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit.lfs,5.4.0.201905070004
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache,5.4.0.201905070004
```

**¿Saben como solucionarlo?**

Comment: yo estoy teniendo el mismo problema, he buscado soluciones pero no encontré ninguna.

Comment: tuve el mismo problema pero, cerré el eclipse volví a abrir y me descargo y actualizo. Tal vez no sea la solución pero a mi me funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error puede venir de que ha habido un problema con la cache de actualización de git si tienes un sitio de software externo para git.

En mi caso lo que hice es lo siguiente:

1. En dialogo de las actualizaciones, desmarca las casillas de relacionadas con git. En tu caso todas menos la de "Marketplace Client".
2. Reinicia el eclipse.
3. Ve al menú `Help` -> `Install new software...`. En el dialogo pulsa en el botón `Manage...`.
4. Quita la casilla del repositorio de Git. En mi caso era la entrada "Egit P2 Repository" con la url `http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates`. Pulsa `Apply and close`.
5. Busca actualizaciones. Debería indicarte que no hay actualizaciones.
6. Vuelve a abrir `Help` -> `Install new software...`.
7. Pega la url en el campo `Work with` y pulsa intro.
8. Asegurate que la casilla `Concact all update sites during install to find required software` está marcada.
9. Del listado de paquetes disponibles, selecciona los que tienen una actualización (el símbolo del paquete tiene unas flechas).
10. Continua con la instalación.
11. Debería actualizarse sin dar el error.

Esto es lo que yo he hecho y me ha funcionado, pero espero que te funcione. La idea es que se refresque la cache del repositorio de paquetes para que eclipse vea las nuevas dependencias.